# Can we call VB6 function from python program?

Tags: python, vb6

I have created a file watcher in python but there is one in built function written in VB6 which i need to call in this python program. Could you please help if this is possible and if so provide an example for same. In below code INI_IO is the one i am trying to call.

```py
def connectMain():

    AppPath = INI_IO("GLOBAL", "AppPath", App.Path, True)
    if AppPath == "":
        AppPath=""

    JobTyp = [Command if Command.isnumeric() else 0]
    AktDate = Now

    server = ''
    Driver = ''
    Database = ''
    uid= ''
    pwd = ''
    connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={   };"
                                "Server = ;"
                                "Database = ;"
                                "uid = ;"
                                "pwd = ;")

    print("S", "Start", "JobTyp = " + JobTyp)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around.

You can change your VB6 program to accept parameters from command line.

And call VB6 exe from command line by Python.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Shell commande like this

```
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("C:\project\python fil.py", 1)    ' Open Notepad.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way round, they want to call VB6 from Python, this is calling Python from VB6.